# CSS inherit not responding to change in parent element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am splitting my page to `.left-side` and `.right-side` to which the `.right-side` has a nav fixed to the top. It was already difficult to get the nav to be the full width of it's parent `.right-side` so I had to use `width: inherit, left: inherit`.

So far so good and looks great!

Now the parent has the ability to with class `active` to increase it's width to 100%. The child nav with width inherit does not respond to that change.

Take a look:

```
.right-side{
  padding-top: 190px;
  width: 83.33333333%;
  float: right;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #fff;
  transition: width 0.5s;
}
.right-side.active{
  width: 100%;
}
nav.navbar {
  background-color: #F1ECD8;
  width: inherit;
  right: 0px;
  left: inherit;
}
```

The right-side responds when adding class `active` but the nav doesn't more or change accordingly with it. How can I fix this?

I should mention, this works fine when I do this manually in chrome dev tools.

Comment: Please use the code snippets to put the HTML and CSS in it.

Comment: My html is all in reactjs :)

Comment: Why does that matter? Grab the output, not the input.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
.right-side{
  padding-top: 190px;
  width: 83.33333333%;
  float: right;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #fff;
  transition: width 0.5s;
}
.right-side.active{
  width: 100%;
}
nav.navbar {
  background-color: #F1ECD8;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  left: 0px;
}
```

Comment: But, i need the navbar to be fixed to the top:S

Answer (score 0):

The easy solution: change `nav.navbar` to `width:100%`. It will take 100% of its parent, and that is `.right-side`

The not-so-easy-to-swallow solution: consider **NOT** using floats for layout, and **NOT** using non-semantic class names like `left-side`, `right-side` for your elements. If you use `display:inline-block` or even flexbox for layout, you'll find you run into less gotchas.